# TypeError: Object of type Properties is not JSON serializable (Sagemaker Pipeline)

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I am trying to set up a Sagemaker pipeline that has 2 steps: preprocessing then training an RF model.
The first step produces 3 outputs: a scaled_data.csv, train.csv, and test.csv. The second step should take train and test CSVs to train the RF model. An error arises when running step 2 stating "TypeError: Object of type Properties is not JSON serializable".

Here is my code for setting the pipeline steps:

```
# upload data from local path to default bucket with prefix raw_data
WORK_DIRECTORY = "data"

input_data = sagemaker_session.upload_data(
    path="{}/{}".format(WORK_DIRECTORY, "dataset.csv"),
    bucket=bucket,
    key_prefix="{}/{}".format(prefix, "input_data"),
)
```

1. setting up the first step (scaling step)

```
scaling_processor = SKLearnProcessor(
    framework_version=FRAMEWORK_VERSION,
    instance_type="ml.m5.4xlarge",
    instance_count=processing_instance_count,
    base_job_name="data-process",
    role=role,
    sagemaker_session=pipeline_session,
)

scaling_processor_args = scaling_processor.run(
    inputs=[
        ProcessingInput(source=input_data, destination="/opt/ml/processing/input"),
    ],
    outputs=[
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="scaled_data", source="/opt/ml/processing/output/scaled_data/"),
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="train", source="/opt/ml/processing/output/train/"),
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="test", source="/opt/ml/processing/output/test/")    ],
    
    code="scripts/preprocess.py",
)

step_process = ProcessingStep(name="DataProcess", step_args=scaling_processor_args)
```

2. setting up the 2nd step (RF Training-BYO mode), here is where the error arises:

```
estimator_cls = sagemaker.sklearn.SKLearn
FRAMEWORK_VERSION = "0.23-1"

rf_processor = FrameworkProcessor(
    estimator_cls,
    FRAMEWORK_VERSION,
    role = role,
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.m5.2xlarge',
    base_job_name='rf-modelling'
)

rf_processor_args = rf_processor.run(
    inputs=[
        ProcessingInput(source=step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs["train"].S3Output.S3Uri,
                        destination="/opt/ml/processing/input"),
        ProcessingInput(source=step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs["test"].S3Output.S3Uri,
                        destination="/opt/ml/processing/input"),    ],
    outputs=[
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="rf_model",source = "/opt/ml/processing/output/")
   ],
    
    code="scripts/train.py",
)

step_train = ProcessingStep(name="RFTrain", step_args=rf_processor_args)
```

An error arises when running step 2 stating "TypeError: Object of type Properties is not JSON serializable". The problem is with the line where I set processingInput for the 2nd step in rf_processor_args.
Any ideas what might cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `run()` you call seems to be incorrect choice, as `run()` is used to run the processing job directly, instead of defining the pipeline steps, which you apparently want. Use `ProcessingStep` directly and feed it with all the necessary arguments:

```py
# Setup the first step (scaling step)

...

# --> Use ProcessingStep directly and provide all the args
step_process = ProcessingStep(
    name="DataProcess",
    processor=scaling_processor,
    inputs=[
        ProcessingInput(source=input_data, destination="/opt/ml/processing/input"),
    ],
    outputs=[
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="scaled_data", source="/opt/ml/processing/output/scaled_data/"),
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="train", source="/opt/ml/processing/output/train/"),
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="test", source="/opt/ml/processing/output/test/"),
    ],
    code="scripts/preprocess.py",
)

# Setup the 2nd step (RF Training-BYO mode)

...

# --> Use ProcessingStep directly and provide all the args
step_train = ProcessingStep(
    name="RFTrain",
    processor=rf_processor,
    inputs=[
        ProcessingInput(source=step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs["train"].S3Output.S3Uri,
                        destination="/opt/ml/processing/input/train"),
        ProcessingInput(source=step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs["test"].S3Output.S3Uri,
                        destination="/opt/ml/processing/input/test"),
    ],
    outputs=[
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="rf_model", source="/opt/ml/processing/output/"),
    ],
    code="scripts/train.py",
)
```